# Prometheus HTTP API - POST Request

Tags: http-post, prometheus, promql, httpapi

We are working with Prometheus HTTP API, and we're sending GET requests to the following endpoint:

```
/api/v1/query
```

At the beginning things worked as expected, but recently when our queries got bigger, request-URI became too large.

Docs says that it is possible to send **POST** request to the same endpoint, and pass the query parameter directly in the request body, instead of passing a query param as part of the URL..

This should solve our problem, but I couldn't find any example or guidelines explaining how to do it.

URL query length is limited, so we are looking for a way to send the query as part of the body :

End-point : http://server:8082/api/v1/query

**Body :**

```
{
    "query": "count(count(node_cpu_seconds_total{instance=~\"iServer.*\",job=\"events_prometheus\"}) by (cpu))"
}
```

**Response Error :**

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "errorType": "bad_data",
    "error": "invalid parameter 'query': parse error at char 1: no expression found in input"
}
```

Just to mention that sending the same query, as a query param, will work and give us the expected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can URL-encode these parameters directly in the request body by using the `POST` method and `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header. This is useful when specifying a large query that may breach server-side URL character limits.
If you use some programming language, you should build these requests like in the example below.

Example code in golang:

```golang
func main() {
    formData := url.Values{
        "query": {"sum(temperature) by(status)"},
        "time":  {"1670859244"},
    }

    client := &http.Client{}

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://localhost:8428/api/v1/query", strings.NewReader(formData.Encode()))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    log.Println(string(body))
}
```

In the response, you should see something like this.

```json
{"status":"success","data":{"resultType":"vector","result":[]}}
```

But in the result, there should be some vector with data.
An example of the response can check here
https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#range-query